# JSTL lib location causing java servlet not accessible, throws error 404

Tags: java, eclipse, jstl, http-status-code-404

So the issue is if the jstl-1.2.jar is placed in apache\lib folder the JSTLs work fine with the JSP pages and they are accessible properly but the Servlets are not accessible and they throw the 404 error.

When I place the jstl-1.2.jar in the WEB-INF/lib folder of the project the error goes away and everything works properly.

So the question is, is this a norm/good practice to include the jar in the WEB-INF/lib folder? Is there any particular reason why this error happens? Am I missing something here?

Note: Using eclipse IDE(Mars), Servlet version 3.0

Thanks in advance

Comment: servlets not accessible ?. u mean servlets doesnt call on the user request.

Comment: `protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
 }`                                                                                                                          This is what i had in the Servlet get method. When i try to go to "http://localhost:8080/webtest/TestServlet" i was getting 404. Does that make sense?

Comment: JSP pages are compiled **into** `Servlet` instances before the page can be served. So your question doesn't logically make sense.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch , When I access"http://localhost:8080/webtest/TestJSTL.jsp" i see the result but when I try to access  "http://localhost:8080/webtest/TestServlet" i get 404. Does that make sense?